# Increase salaries in Oracle HR Schema

Tags: sql, oracle

The question is:
How to increase salaries by 10% of employees who are not the head of any other department. (HR-schema)?

```
UPDATE Employees SET salary = salary * 0.1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT department_name
 FROM departments D 
    JOIN employees E 
        ON (D.manager_id<>E.employee_id)
        group by department_name);
```

But above code updates all records of Employees table.
Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: How are you identifying if someone is head of the department?

Comment: In addition to your selectivity issue, your math is wrong. If your current salary is 50, then your formual (salary * 0.1)  will make the new salary 5.  I leave it as an exercise for the student to find the correct operation for increasing a number by 10 percent.

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward:

```
update employees e set
  e.salary = e.salary * 1.1
where e.employee_id not in (select m.manager_id
                            from employees m
                            where m.manager_id is not null
                           )
```

---

Scott's sample schema (as I don't have HR):

```
SQL> select empno, ename, mgr, sal
  2  from emp
  3  order by mgr;

     EMPNO ENAME             MGR        SAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7902 FORD             7566       3000  -- also a manager
      7788 SCOTT            7566       3000  -- also a manager
      7900 JAMES            7698        950
      7499 ALLEN            7698       1600
      7521 WARD             7698       1250
      7844 TURNER           7698       1500
      7654 MARTIN           7698       1250
      7934 MILLER           7782       1300
      7876 ADAMS            7788       1100
      7698 BLAKE            7839       2850  -- also a manager  
      7566 JONES            7839       2975  -- also a manager
      7782 CLARK            7839       2450  -- also a manager
      7369 SMITH            7902        800
      7839 KING                        5000  -- also a manager

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Out of 14 employees, 6 of them are managers which means that `UPDATE` should raise salaries for the remaining 8 employees. So, let's do it:

Using `in`:

```
SQL> update emp e set
  2    e.sal = e.sal * 1.1
  3  where e.empno not in (select m.mgr
  4                        from emp m
  5                        where m.mgr is not null   --> I was missing this
  6                       );

8 rows updated.
```

Or, using `not exists`:

```
SQL> update emp e set
  2    e.sal = e.sal * 1.1
  3    where not exists (select null
  4                      from emp m
  5                      where m.mgr = e.empno
  6                     );

8 rows updated.

SQL>
```

Comment: Then all employees are also managers. If you disagree, please, post sample data (CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements).

Comment: In fact i use standard hr schema table Employees. Did you try to update with the same HR Employees table?

Comment: I don't have HR schema in my database, but I have Scott. I edited the answer and added some more code. Also, I have to apologize: using `IN`, the "president" King - who doesn't have a manager - made query not to do anything; `where m.manager_id is not null` was missing. Fixed now so - please - try again.